# Delphi 7 uninstall and install error

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have installed first delphi 5 and then installed delphi 7 a year ago. And I was using Delphi 5 only most of time. After I installed Delphi 7 it was working good and created 2-3 applications with that.

But now after 6 months when i am trying to run Delphi 7 its giving me some errors. So I uninstalled the Delphi 7 and tried to re-install but the acing same problem. I tried twice and same results. :(  I am not able to view any forms also in Delphi 7.  And there is no option also to add new form also.

When I run newly installed Delphi 7 its trying to load some components from delphi5 directory. How can I solve this problem?

Delphi 5 installed path: D:\Delphi5

Delphi 7 installed path: C:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi7

Below is error I am getting while loading Delphi 7:

```
Exception EPackageError in module rtl70.bpl at 00017EAA
Can't Load package D:\Delphi5\bin\delphide70.bpl
Can't Load package D:\Delphi5\bin\direct70.bpl
Can't Load package D:\Delphi5\bin\delphivclide70.bpl
Can't Load package D:\Delphi5\bin\MsgInoCFG.bpl
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you install Delphi7 on top of your Delphi5 installation?

Comment: yes. I installed Delphi 7 on top of Delphi 5.

Comment: Then I suggest you uninstall Delphi7, delete your installation folder (D:\Delphi5) and then reinstall Delphi7.

Comment: @iMan: Thanks for reply, but I dont want to uninstall Delphi 5 as my all applications depends on that and installed many components for Delphi 5. Please let me know if there is any solution.

Comment: @Naren: By "on top of", iMan is asking if you installed in the same folder. If you did, you broke both Delphi 5 and 7, and have no choice but to remove both and reinstall from scratch. They should never go in the same folder (in fact, they cannot and were never designed to - D7 is a new version of Delphi, not an upgrade for D5).

Comment: Well you have no choice but to uninstall Delphi7, then Delphi5, delete the installation folder, remove all the RTL and VCL packages from Windows\System32, and then reinstall Delphi5 if you can not migrate to Delphi7. I don't believe Windows Installer can undo the major damage Delphi7 has done to your Delphi5 installation.

Comment: @iMan Biglari, you should post it as answer, as this is the only remedy to this situation.

Comment: @Ken: Delphi 7 is installed in C:\Programs Files\Borland\Delphi7 while Delphi 5 is installed in D:\Delphi5. Installed the both versions in dierent directories and it was the same when i installed first time when they worked without errors. I am not getting why Delphi 7 is pointing to Delphi 5 path?? Is there anywhere mentioed this Delphi5 path??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Windows registry might have the wrong values (although I don't know how they would have gotten fouled up from what you describe). Use the Start menu's search control (Windows 7) and type `RegEdit` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open the registry editor. Go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Borland\Delphi\7.0` (and the same path in the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` tree), and check for anything related to the Delphi 5 location in `Known Packages`, `Known IDE Packages`, or anywhere else.

The alternative is to simply uninstall Delphi 7, and then go into `RegEdit` as above, and rename both the `Borland\Delphi\7.0` entries described above. Use the `Control Panel->System and Security\System` dialog, click `Advanced Settings` in the left panel, and then click the `Environmental Variables` button, and make sure there are no entries in the `PATH` related to Delphi 7. Then reinstall Delphi 7 like you did above and see if it fixes everything. **Make sure you only rename the entries and don't delete them, in case you do something wrong; you can always name them back again.**

Comment: Bingo!!!  :)  Thanks ken.  ound one varible in in enviromental Variable which is pointing to that location. Removed that and all got worked. I dont know how it got added but still resolved the issue.. Good catch.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well you have no choice but to uninstall Delphi7, then Delphi5, delete the installation folder, remove all the RTL and VCL packages from Windows\System32, and then reinstall Delphi5 if you can not migrate to Delphi7. I don't believe Windows Installer can undo the major damage Delphi7 has done to your Delphi5 installation.

Comment: "major damage Delphi7 has done to your Delphi5 installation' - I have installed Delphi 5 and 7 side-by-side many many times, with no side effects. I don't believe the damage was caused by D7.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a reply i got from one of the technical support from Embarcadero:

> Hello,   My name is Oscar Njumbe. I am looking at this case.
>   Uinstall the product from your Windows uinstaller and make sure you
>   select the option to remove all registry entries to completely
>   unistall from your machine.   In case you forgot to select this
>   option, follow the generic instructions below to uninstall the
>   product.
>
> 1. Uninstall the product via the "Embarcadero Rad Studio XE" entry in  " Program and Features "  in the  Control Panel
>
>    1. Remove the C:\Program Files\Embarcadero\Rad Studio\8.0 directory
>    2. Remove the C:\Users\Public\Public Documents\Rad Studio directory
>    3. Remove the c:\ProgramData\Embarcadero\Rad Studio\8.0 directory
>    4. Remove the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Embarcadero\BDS\8.0 registry key
>    5. Remove the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Embarcadero\BDS\8.0 registry key
>    6. Remove folders with a GUID name in C:\ProgramData\  Such as C:\ProgramData{7DE921C9-42C8-4DA3-8A44-043C3349FD1D}
> 2. Remove the following files from Windows\System32:  8a. *150.bpl  8b. *150.jdbg  8c. *150.xml  8d. bdeadmin.*  8e. cc32*.dll
> 3. Reboot the machine.   Please note this case will be closed on Wednesday 7th November if no response is received.   Best Regards
>      Oscar Njumbe  EMEA Multi-Lingual Technical Support Engineer.